# If leaves come off a plant with little resistance, does that always mean they're dead?

Tags: leaves, deadheading

Spent flowers and old brown leaves tend to fall off at a slight touch. Sometimes reasonably green ones do as well though. If a leaf or flower comes off without having to pull or snap anything, does that always mean it has reached the end of its life? Or do I need to be more delicate as these loose leaves are still living?

Comment: Intro to this article on Abscisic acid is interesting: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/jipb.12899 Relevance here probably depends on the specific plants involved.